# sql query, where domains is in subscriptions, but not in block or hits

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM domains
WHERE domains_id IN
      (
        SELECT domains_subscriptions_domain
        FROM domains_subscriptions
        WHERE domains_subscriptions_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
      )
AND domains_id NOT IN
      (
        SELECT domains_block_domain
        FROM domains_block
        WHERE domains_block_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
          AND domains_block_member='$_SESSION[member]'
      )
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I would like to take all domains that are in domains, which are also in domains_subscriptions, but then they are not in domains_blocks. which works well with the query above. But then I want to be able to add

```
AND domains_id NOT IN
      (
         SELECT domains_hits_domain 
         FROM domains_hits
         WHERE domains_hits_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
            AND domains_hits_member='$_SESSION[member]'
      )
```

this to the query so it also filters out domains what are in the domains_hits table, but it currently gives me all the domains as I presume it is saying it would only filter out domains that are in both the domains_block and domains_hits tables, but I want it to be either!

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM domains
WHERE domains_id IN
      (
        SELECT domains_subscriptions_domain
        FROM domains_subscriptions
        WHERE domains_subscriptions_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
      )
AND domains_id NOT IN
      (
        SELECT domains_block_domain
        FROM domains_block
        WHERE domains_block_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
          AND domains_block_member='$_SESSION[member]'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT domains_hits_domain 
        FROM domains_hits
        WHERE domains_hits_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
           AND domains_hits_member='$_SESSION[member]'
      )
ORDER BY RAND()
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM domains
WHERE domains_id IN
      (
        SELECT domains_subscriptions_domain
        FROM domains_subscriptions
        WHERE domains_subscriptions_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
      )
AND NOT (
      domains_id IN
      (
        SELECT domains_block_domain
        FROM domains_block
        WHERE domains_block_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
          AND domains_block_member='$_SESSION[member]'
      )
      OR
      domains_id IN
      ( 
        SELECT domains_hits_domain 
        FROM domains_hits
        WHERE domains_hits_selmgec='$_SESSION[selmgec]'
           AND domains_hits_member='$_SESSION[member]'
      )
    )
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! your first query works, but the second one does not.

Comment: yeah that works fine now! so which is the best one to use? Say for instance the second part domains_hits a member could turn this on and off! so say they have a filter form and can check whether they want to see or not see domains they have previously seen?

Comment: $hits = "OR
      domains_id IN
      ( 
        SELECT domains_hits_domain 
        FROM domains_hits
        WHERE domains_hits_selmgec='2'
           AND domains_hits_member='1'
      )";

Can I have this@? and then replace your code with $hits?

Comment: Yes, but why you want to do this?

Comment: well I will have a search form and members will have a check box with exclude domains already seen?

Comment: You have 3 checkboxes which represents `subscriptions`, `block` and `hits` and you want to include or exclude some types of domains?

Comment: Sorry will explain better. There will be one checkbox for the hits. The other two subscriptions and block are automatically part of the query these can not be changed.

Comment: See @MahmoudGamal post he have query with better performance. For option with hits you can modify `WHERE clause` as `WHERE b.domains_block_domain IS NULL
  AND (h.domains_hits_domain IS NULL OR $_SESSION[IncludeHitsChecked] = 1);`

Comment: ok thanks. I changed $_SESSION[IncludeHitsChecked] = 0 as when they check the box I want it to be 1 and this does as I want. thanks for all your help